# JxBrowser remote debugging does not work in chrome, returns blank page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, remote-debugging, jxbrowser

I am trying to inspect JxBrowser in chrome which has remoteDebuggingPort 9224. It does work in jxBrowser itself but I need to inspect it in chrome. When I type Url localhost:9224 in the chrome and hit enter, it does show Inspectable pages but when I select the link, it shows white page.

Inspecting in JxBrowser Url: http://localhost:9224 [*Works as expected*]
[image]

Inspected in Chrome Url: http://localhost:9224 [*Does not work as expected*]

[image]

I noticed, both redirects to the same URL after clicking on inspactable pages

```
https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_rev/@e8e14b69c41a5a461c15fa5d1065ec28c49890ac/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9224/devtools/page/9FBC7B2B083CF0D2A48743F3C161FF98
```

Comment: what happens if you try opening `chrome://inspect/#devices` in chrome while jxbrowser is open?

Answer (score 0):

See the docs of JXBrowser here: https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/engine.html#remote-debugging-port

You need the exact same Chromium version as the JXBrowser uses. Its recommended to use a JXBrowser instance to debug JXBrowser.

Comment: not exactly true. There was a time when Chrome updated to the newest version and JxBrowser was still stuck on an old chromium version, I can't debug using `http://localhost:<PORT#>`. I was able to solve this by going to `chrome://inspect/#devices`. The JxBrowser instance will show up there and I can inspect there. Ever since then, I have used this method to debug JxBrowser instances (even at 7.10).